# Dynamically Removing Record from pageBlockSection in Visualforce

Tags: jquery, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I've built a Visualforce page with the below JQuery snippet that dynamically adds a pageBlockSection when the button "Add Dev" is clicked.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Add Dev" action="{!NewDev}" reRender="devs" oncomplete="scroll();"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    function scroll(){
        var docHeight = j$(document).height();
        var winHeight = j$(window).height();

        j$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: docHeight - winHeight}, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Below is the method for adding the newDev.  But what I want to do is add another button within the pageBlockSection that executes a removeDev method that, when clicked, removes the pageBlockSection that it's in from both the view and the list dev.

```
public void NewDev(){
    devs.add(new Development__c(Change_Set__c = changeSet.Id));
}
```

I've tried deleting the dev through a DML operation, which causes an error.  I've tried removing the dev with the .remove list method but that doesn't seem to be the right approach.  I'm stuck.  Any ideas?

Comment: So you can add the section, and it executes the apex method correctly.
What VF code have you tried to get the remove button to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can't deleting the dev through a DML operation because you not insert him before.
Change the function NewDev to

```
public void NewDev(){
 Development__c dev = new Development__c(Change_Set__c = changeSet.Id);   
 insert dev; 
  devs.add(dev);
}
```